# Maven projects needs to be built to compile?

Tags: java, maven

At work I have encountered a couple of projects that in order to compile, it was needed to `mvn clean install` before. From the architectural point of view, why would it be planned to be like that? Shouldn't the code be independent from the runtime generated code before the deployment? 
I am missing something here.. 
If it is contemplated such a thing, do you have any example of a real case that it may be useful?(mixing compilation time code and runtime code)

Comment: `install` also compiles, so I guess I might need some details and/or clarification.

Comment: Maven install puts the reusable maven artifact in the local maven repository but has nothing to do with installing the executable into the runtime environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any java code is executable only after they are compiled. So to use or to be used, java code has to be compiled. Maven install also compiles and add the executable files in local maven repository for the other classes to make use of it